# display number of users

Tags: php, userscripts

Is there a way to show the total number of users of a network who have signed up? I just ran into an example [here](http://www.badoo.com/) (at the bottom of the page on the right) and wonder how they do it...

Answer (score 3):

Not nearly enough info.  But here's a shot in the dark:

```
select count(*) from users;
```

Answer (score 1):

When a user signs up they create an entity in a database.  All it's doing is counting the number of users in the database and displaying that number.  Easy peasy.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do that but it does it dynamically. It should be using some javascript, I don't want to reload the page every time to show an updated state...

Comment: You can use an AJAX call to update it dynamically.

Comment: thanks! anywhere I could read up on that, please?

Comment: I'd go with an ajax library like jQuery.  Easy, powerful.  http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code they use Javascript, but not any ajax or something, the counter seems to be updated using this...

```
this.value + Math.round(Math.random() * 3)
```

amazing :D